# how understand my variable is vacuum in use of \ifx?

Tags: macros

I want use `\ifx` and do some thing if my variable`\myvariable`is vacuum . how do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
\def\tmp{vacuum}
\ifx\myvariable\tmp yes\else no\fi
```

Comment: I think you don't understand my idea. vacuum means that my variable don't have any input:`\newcommand{\myvariable}{}`

Comment: @MojtabaMansouri It was unlikely that anyone guessed that:-) well exactly the same just define `\tmp` as `{}`

Comment: thank you.the reason that i don't understand was i use `{}` in your code but don't work for me. i use `\newcommand{\tmp}{}` and it work

Comment: @MojtabaMansouri ah OK, yes (or `\long\def\tmp{}`)